# Is std::to_string a cross-platform?

Tags: c++, c++11, cross-platform, std, tostring

Is `std::to_string` a cross platform operation?
Will it be compiled and work well for all platforms? if it is not, what is the alternative?

thanks

Comment: Like everything in the standard library. It is "cross platform" for platforms with standards-compliant implementations.

Comment: It's in the standard library, and **should** be available on every platform compliant with the standard. That said, I know at least one platform where it isn't available: Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's part of the Standard Library, so there are good probabilities that you will find on every platform a C++11 compliant compiler supporting it.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is.The standard defines what it means to be a C++ compiler, and all compilers claiming to be C++ should conform to the standard; any that don't can be considered buggy. All of the major compilers try their best to be conforming.

There are two standards to be concerned with here, C++03 and C++11. Since C++11 is new there are some features that won't be implemented in every compiler. If you stick to C++03 you should find wide conformity.

Everything in the std namespace should be part of the standard, by definition.

Answer (score 1):

It is as long as you have in the given platform an implementation of the standard library which is conform to the standard.